# Remove organisation account from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook

2 months ago since starting WFH, I set up my Outlook to receive emails from my company. Since then I always see 
Windows Notification: Fix your account

Now, I found that I cannot download any apps from Windows Store
[image]

Searched around and found this could be related to the account issue.

So I decide to remove the company's account from my PC.
[image]

I clicked the company's account and clicked Manage, it opened a Website which has no place for me to remove it from my PC.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-remove-a-work-or-school-account-from-windows/22403d43-91b6-4724-b509-ab3d28031e05

1) Go to settings window

2) Select "Accounts"

3) Select "Access work or school"

4) This should show a window where you can select the account and choose disconnect.